# Pymongo cannot encode object for a set argument

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, pymongo

I'm scraping a site and saving to mongodb using pymongo.

What the scraper does is for each product it adds it to an array, when there are no more products it saves that array to mongodb.

A product looks like this:

```
product = {
        'title': title,
        'url': url,
        'thumbnail': image,
        'reviews': {total_reviews, rating}
    }
```

and the pymongo looks like this:

```
collection.update_one(
    {'_id': 1}, {'$set': {'api.results': productList}})
```

The error I'm getting is: `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {'4.5', 'N/A'}`. I've looked for solutions but the ones I found only show how to find items not update. How would I go around solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{foo, bar}` is a set of `foo` and `bar`.

Sets are not directly storable in MongoDB, you need to convert them to a type that MongoDB understands such as a list.

If you want a list, use `[]` brackets.

If you wanted a mapping, specify the keys (`{foo: foo, bar: bar}`).

Comment: ur a literal lifesaver I can't belive it was that simple. Thank you so much.